# How to force git to add dotfiles to repository

Tags: git, file, dotfiles

Git seems to always ignore these.

When I type `git add .`, dotfiles in `GIT_DIR` are added, but not from subdirectories. On the other hand, `git add subdir/.dotfile` won't work.

I tried `git add -f` and putting `!.*` in `GIT_DIR/.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: Does "touch .dotfile; git add .dotfile" work in the top level directory? This looks a bit like '.*' is listed in a .gitignore file (maybe in the subdirectory), but when I test this (admittedly with a fairly new version of git) I get a stonking warning suggesting the use of the -f flag to git add.

Answer (score 33):

`git add .` and `git add dir/.dot` work fine for me with the unadorned 1.6.6.1 and 1.7.0 versions of Git that I have handy right now.

```
% git --version
git version 1.6.6.1
% git ls-files -o
.baz/baz
.foo
bar/.bar
quuux/quuux
quux
% git add .
% git ls-files -o
% git ls-files 
.baz/baz
.foo
bar/.bar
quuux/quuux
quux
```

What version of Git are you using? Are your subdirs actually submodules (which are managed independently)?

“dot files” are not excluded by default, but maybe some bit of configuration on your system, repository, or working tree has them set that way. If they show up in `git ls-files --exclude-standard -oi` then they are being ignored and "!.*" is the right way to ‘unignore’ them. But to be effective, that pattern has to be in the right place. Ignores are processed in this order:

- **.gitignore** of the immediately containing directory, then
- **.gitignore** of the parent directory (each parent, up to the repository root), then
- **$GIT_DIR/info/exclude**, then
- the file reported by `git config core.excludesfile` (which could be set by

  - **$GIT_DIR/config**,
  - **$HOME/.gitconfig**, or
  - the system config file (try `GIT_EDITOR=echo git config --system --edit` to get its pathname)).

When a pathname matches a pattern in one file, subsequent files are not consulted. The last match in each file “wins”. A pattern in **$GIT_DIR/info/exclude** can never override a pattern in a **.gitignore** file. So, if the files are being ignored (per `git ls-files --exclude-standard -oi`) and if "!.*" in **$GIT_DIR/info/exclude** is ineffective, then check all the applicable `.gitignore` files for the culprit.

Answer (score 20):

You can add them specifically by pathname, e.g.,

```
git add */.*
```

or

```
find . -name '.[a-z]*' -exec git add '{}' ';'
```

(It's good to be careful with the `-name` because you don't necessarily want to pick up every directory with its `.` entry.)

But by far **the easiest way to do this is with `git gui`**.  Just click on the files.

Comment: Which GUI? I'm searching Git tool which shows these files and tried Giggle, Git Cola and gitg and they not showing .files and I don't see any option to enable display them...

Comment: @Line from the command prompt, type "git gui" and the prepackaged gui should execute (on Windows.)

Comment: @avgvstvs, thank You, but what if I only use Linux (newest Ubuntu/Fedora)? :)

Comment: @Line, the download page forget says they support "git gui" and "gitk."  The command might just be `git gitk`

Comment: @Line, verified:  `sudo apt-get install gitk` then in a directory with a `.git` folder, just type `gitk` and you've got "git-gui" for Linux.

Comment: The problem is that when you have many files starting with dot, calling `git add` for each file takes a really long time.

Answer (score 2):

If there are only few .dotfiles you need to add, I recommend using `-f` flag since simple `git add .yourDotFile` does not work on **git version 2.28.8** and you do not want to mess with global `.gitignore`.  Therefore use `git add .yourDotFile -f`

Answer (score 2):

I just forced it with:

```
git add . -f
```

Cheers.

Comment: This will add everything and ignore .gitignore files; it is not recommended.
You should specify the file name git add [filename] -f

Answer (score 1):

i use

```
find . -type f | grep -vP '^.\/.git' |  xargs git add
```

the `grep -vP '^.\/.git'` exclude everthing wich start with `.git` and find get all files include all hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

I dont like the idea of using a 'find' as it might find things you told git to ignore.  You could use a bash script.  This script will only 'add' a file that is modified, not untracked:

```
#!/bin/bash
addFile=false

theseLines=($(git status))
for thisLine in "${theseLines[@]}" ; do

  if [[ "${addFile}" == 'true' ]] ; then
    git add $thisLine
    addFile=false
  fi
  if [[ "${thisLine}" == 'modified:' ]] ; then
    addFile=true
    #echo 'the next line will be a file that should be added'
  fi

done
```