# GIT clone not getting files starting with a dot (.htaccess,.htpasswd)

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'm cloning a repository from Github with GIT, in a remote environment running CentOs, using:

```
git clone https://myuser:mypass@github.com/Myrepository/repo.git
```

and is checking out all the files, except the ones starting with a dot

> .htaccess
>   .htpasswd

Notes:

1. The missing files show up on the Github repository

[image: github]

2. These files are not included in .gitignore
3. I'm listing the files on the server by using `ls -a` command

[image: server]

**Is there any flag I need to add in order to checkout these files too?**

---

**[SOLUTION]**

The problem wasn't with the git clone command, the missing dotfiles were due to another command executed afterwards

```
mv /path/one/* /path/two
```

Which moved everything except the dotfiles.

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Check your gitignore file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force git to add dotfiles to repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352455/force-git-to-add-dotfiles-to-repository).  CAVEAT: Make sure you've added/committed the .dot files to your remote repository first, before you try cloning again.

Comment: My dot files are committed to the repository, and they are not listed in my .gitignore file

Comment: Normally, you should get all files. Are you using a Linux system? There, files starting with dots are hidden per default.

Comment: Can you run `git status`? does it say anything about the missing files?

Comment: If the files were committed to the remote repository, then git clone should absolutely copy them.  They're either not actualy in the repo (my guess) or you're not displaying them (for *nix, you must `ls -a`).  Try `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`

Answer (score 5):

Please note that "dotfiles" are usually hidden by default in most operating systems. This applies whether you are using User or Command Line Interface.

If using CLI try adding `-a` flag to `ls` when listing the files in the git repo:

```
ls -a
```

As seen in `man ls`:

> -a      Include directory entries whose names begin with a dot (.).

Comment: Hi Mathielo, thanks for your comment, I'm checking the files with ls -a

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, I honestly believe the dot files in question were never actually added to the git index and committed.

Please review this link:

- [Force git to add dotfiles to repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352455/force-git-to-add-dotfiles-to-repository)

To "see" hidden .dot files on a *nix host (OSX, Linux, BSD, etc), use `ls -a`

To see the files under Git control in your remote repo, use `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`  or simply `git ls-files`.

It also wouldn't hurt to double-check your `.gitignore` file(s).  Remember - any subdirectory might have it's own, separate .gitignore.

'Hope that helps

ADDENDUM:

Thank you for the additional info you posted:

> Notes:
>
> 1. The missing files show up on the Github repository
>
> [image: Github screenshot]

This definitely shows the files exist on the remote filesystem (good!).  But I'm *not* sure they're necessarily under git control.  Again: `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` can tell you for sure what is and isn't under Git control.