# git not adding folder and sub folders

Tags: git

I want to add the .idea folder to git (unlike most devs who want to ignore it). I have tried all the solutions at:

[Recursively add the entire folder to a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743549/recursively-add-the-entire-folder-to-a-repository)

but nothing worked. My gitignore only has this:

`**/build/
.gradle`

I'm at a loss of why none of the files get added.

Comment: Is there anything in the folder?  Git wont add empty folders

Comment: Yes there are lots of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from here: [Force git to add dotfiles to repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352455/force-git-to-add-dotfiles-to-repository)

> “dot files” are not excluded by default, but maybe some bit of
>   configuration on your system, repository, or working tree has them set
>   that way. If they show up in git ls-files --exclude-standard -oi then
>   they are being ignored and "!.*" is the right way to ‘unignore’ them.
>   But to be effective, that pattern has to be in the right place.
>   Ignores are processed in this order:
>
> ```
> .gitignore of the immediately containing directory, then
> .gitignore of the parent directory (each parent, up to the repository root), then
> $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, then
> the file reported by git config core.excludesfile (which could be set by
>     $GIT_DIR/config,
>     $HOME/.gitconfig, or
>     the system config file (try GIT_EDITOR=echo git config --system --edit to get its pathname)).
> ```

Or add them specifically by pathname, e.g.,

```
git add */.*
```

or

```
find . -name '.[a-z]*' -exec git add '{}' ';'
```

If nothing of this work, another (maybe not very beautiful) solution is trying with creating a symbolic link like:

```
ln -s ./idea ./.idea
```

Hope it helps!