# How to add hidden files in Git

Tags: git, github

How do you add hidden files in like .flake8 in git?  Git add . does not work and not even adding subdirectories. Gitignore is not the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352455/force-git-to-add-dotfiles-to-repository

Answer (score 1):

For individual files

```
git add .hiddenfile
```

for file groups

```
git add .hidden*
```

and if in a subdirectory,

```
git add directory
```

will include the hidden files in that directory.

Also see [Force git to add dotfiles to repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352455/force-git-to-add-dotfiles-to-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing fancy, just

```
git add .flake8
```

PS. `git add .` also must work. In what way it doesn't work for you?

Comment: git add . does not add .flake8 and sub directories.  I check .gitignore and it is not the issue.  I tried git add .flake8 and it does not add .flake8 after checking with git status.

Comment: That's strange. Well, a dot `.` means "the current directory"; check that the current directory is the root of the repo when you run `git add .`

Comment: git rev-parse --show-toplevel verifies I got correct root directory. Same as pwd except pwd does nto add :  to c like c: in windows OS.

Comment: Is it the same as `pwd`?